# Screenshare without extensions

Tags: webrtc

I found this code to perform screensharing:

```
let displayMediaOptions = {video: true, audio: false};
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions)
.then(function(stream){
video_el.srcObject = stream;
})
```

[Working Demo](http://thescreenshare.com)

However, I would like to automatically share the screen contents of an application tab via a button, without invoking the popup for user selection. How is that possible?

Comment: It is not possible because of Privacy and security reasons. The go-ahead permission to use getDisplayMedia() cannot be persisted for reuse. The user must be prompted for permission every time. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia